# PHP: Search mysql database using multiple select dropdown lists?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to search MYSQL database using multiple Dropdown lists on my page.

However, there is a small twist in this search function.

Basically, I need to make sure *All* the criteria (all the multiple select dropdonw values) match the items and if they do match then show the result!

At the moment, my code shows the results even if one of the dropdown values match the items which is not what i am trying to do.

This is my code:

```
$searchList = "";
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `product_details`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON product_details.id=ATTRIBUTES.id";//Query stub
    if(isset($_POST['keyword']) && !empty($_POST['keyword'])){

        foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){
            $currentproduct = $_POST['product'];
            $cat = $_POST['cat'];
                ##NOPE##$sql .= $clause."`".$c."` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
                $sql .= $clause . " (ATTRIBUTES.attr LIKE BINARY '$c') AND ATTRIBUTES.sub_cat_name='$currentproduct'";
               $clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
            }
        }
        $sql .= " GROUP BY product_details.id";
        //print "SQL Query: $sql<br />"; //<-- Debug SQl syntax.
        // Run query outside of foreach loop so it only runs one time.
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
```

I even tried to remove the `isset` and did  `if(!empty($_POST['keyword'])){` but i still get results even if one of the dropdown lists values match the items credentials.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here as I thought using `if(!empty($_POST['keyword'])){` should solve this issue but it hasn't.

Could someone please advise on this issue?

any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: I changed the CODE to the following and it doesn't display anything:

```
$clause = " WHERE ";//Initial clause
$sql="SELECT *
FROM `product_details`
INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON product_details.id=ATTRIBUTES.id";//Query stub
            $currentproduct = $_POST['product'];
            $cat = $_POST['cat'];
            if(!empty($_POST['keyword'])){

        foreach($_POST['keyword'] as $c){
            if(!empty($c)){

                ##NOPE##$sql .= $clause."`".$c."` LIKE '%{$c}%'";
                $sql .= $clause . " (ATTRIBUTES.attr LIKE BINARY '$c') AND ATTRIBUTES.sub_cat_name='$currentproduct'";
               $clause = " AND ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
            }
        }
        $sql .= " GROUP BY product_details.id";
        //print "SQL Query: $sql<br />"; //<-- Debug SQl syntax.
        // Run query outside of foreach loop so it only runs one time.
        $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
        //var_dump($query); //<-- Debug query results.
        // Check that the query ran fine.
       if (!$query) {
            print "ERROR: " . mysqli_error($db_conx);
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$clause = " OR ";//Change  to OR after 1st WHERE
```

The above OR operator will cause your where criteria to select a record even if 1 keyword matches the attr field. Change it to " AND " to expect all keywords to apply.

Furthermore, ... AND ATTRIBUTES.sub_cat_name='$currentproduct'" criterion seems to apply to all keywords, so this criterion should be added once, not at every iteration of the loop. $currentproduct = $_POST['product']; row should also be moved in fron of the loop.

EDIT: to reflect to changing the opreator to AND and not having any rows returned.

```
...ATTRIBUTES.attr LIKE BINARY '$c'...
```

If there are no wildcards in $c, then the above criterion will require the word to match the attr field as if = operator had been used, which is unlikely to happen. Wildcards must be included in the search: '%$c%'

Plus some protection from sql injection would also be nice.

EDIT2:
If each attribue is stored in its own record, then it complicates things a little bit, since the where criteria is evaluated against a single record, not a collection of them.

I'll give you a sample select command, but you will have to incorporate it into your php code.

```
select product_details.* FROM product_details INNER JOIN
    (select product_details.id, count(ATTRIBUTES.id) as total
     FROM `product_details`
     INNER JOIN `ATTRIBUTES` ON product_details.id=ATTRIBUTES.id
     WHERE ATTRIBUTES.attr in (...)
     GROUP BY product_details.id
     HAVING total=...) as t
on t.id=product_details.id
```

The subquery counts how many attributes were matched for a product and eliminates those, where the count does not equal to the number of parameters submitted via the form. The outer query gets the product details for those, where the count matched.

For the ... in the in() clause you need to provide a comma separated, ' enclosed list of the keywords, like: "'computer', 'apple'". Use implode() function in php and sztring concatenation to get the results.

For the ... in the having clause substitute the number of keywords in the $_POST['keyword'] array (you should check in the code if it's an array or just a single value, though).

Still, you should consider the impact of sql injection on your code.

Comment: When i change the "OR" to "AND" my entire code stops working and its not showing any results from the mysql!

Comment: Stops working and not showing results are two entirely different things! Stops working means that the code is broken and produces an aeeror message, while not showing any results means (in this particular case) that no records satisfied the selection criteria. Can you pls be specific which happens after you make the change?

Comment: Yes, sure. when i change the OR to AND, i get  no results at all (nothing). and I get no errors on my page either!

Comment: If it stops working, then pls provide the error message. If it only returns an empty resultset, then I would like to see what's in $_POST['keyword']. My suspicion is that it contains just words like "computer". Which would mean that when you use the like operator, there are no wildcards used, so your query will only match if all keywords exactly match the attr field, which is unlikely

Comment: Please view my edit. also, I get no errors as i mentioned before. And yes, the value of keywords are like computers, apples, t-shirts etc etc...

Comment: Updated the answer. Another question sprung to my mind, however: how do you exactly store your attributes? Each attribute in its own record where the product_details.id is common through these records or all attributes are stored in a single record's attr field separated by a separator character?

Comment: Also, yes to your question. Each attribute in its own record where the product_details.id is common through these records

Comment: sorry ingore my message about the error. i deleted it.. it was me leaving an extra ' sign in the wildecard. but still i don't get any results even with the wild card. and no errors either!

Comment: sorry I have no idea how to use your code!! it just doesn't make sense to be honest!!

Comment: You need to be specific in your question.

Comment: I really don't know how I could be any more specific to be honest... is there anything that I could do to make it more clear and to be more specific?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91433/discussion-between-shadow-and-h-history).