# mysql join table query 2 values

Tags: mysql, join

I'm trying to run a query on my database to show products which has the attribute chosen

Table 1 `Products`

```
ID | Product Name
---|-----------------
1    Red Car
2    Blue Car
3    Yellow Car
```

Table 2 `Attributes`

```
Product ID | Attribute ID
-----------|-----------------
1            3
2            3
3            3
1            4
2            4
```

For example i only want to display products which have attribute 3 and 4 set the it should only show the red and blue car. But not the yellow car as the product as not got a attribute set for product id 3

Comment: I have just answered the exactly same question in another SO topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32945964/php-search-mysql-database-using-multiple-select-dropdown-lists

Comment: I wish the duplicate thing worked better

Comment: You can find something similar here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32948681/mysql-filter-on-many-to-many/32949847

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to solve this; the most straight-forward would probably be to use a couple of `exists` clauses, or join the `attributes` table twice, but you could also use `group by` and `having` clauses to accomplish the same result:

```
-- option 1: using multiple exists clauses
select p.id, p.productname
from Products p
where exists (select 1 from Attributes a where p.ID = a.ProductID and a.AttributeID = 3)
  and exists (select 1 from Attributes a where p.ID = a.ProductID and a.AttributeID = 4);

-- option 2: using multiple joins
select p.id, p.productname
from Products p
join Attributes a3 on p.ID = a3.ProductID
join Attributes a4 on p.ID = a4.ProductID
where a3.AttributeID = 3
  and a4.AttributeID = 4;

-- option 3: using aggregate and having
select p.id, p.productname
from Products p
join Attributes a on p.ID = a.ProductID
group by p.id, p.productname
having sum(case when a.AttributeID = 3 then 1 else 0 end) > 0
   and sum(case when a.AttributeID = 4 then 1 else 0 end) > 0;

-- option 4: using having and count
select p.id, p.productname
from Products p
join Attributes a on p.ID = a.ProductID
where a.AttributeID in (3,4)
group by p.id, p.productname
having count(distinct a.attributeid) = 2;
```

Which way is best for you would probably depend on what result you need and indexes et cetera.

[Sample SQL Fiddle.](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/48237/1)