# Query a table that have 2 cols with multiple criteria

Tags: sql, performance, sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with the following structure and Example data:

[image]

Now I want to query the records that have `value` equals to `#` and `@`.
For example according to the above image, It should returns `1` and `2`

```
id
-----
1 
2
```

Also if the parameters were `@`, `#` and `$` It should give us `1`. Because only the records with id `1` have all the given values.

```
id
-----
1
```

Comment: I answered a similar question yesterday; you might find it helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32959889/mysql-join-table-query-2-values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a group by and having to get the distinct Id's that contain a distinct count of the number of items you're looking for

```
SELECT Id
FROM Table
WHERE Value IN ('#','$')
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Value) = 2

SELECT Id
FROM Table
WHERE Value IN ('#','$','@')
GROUP BY Id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Value) = 3
```

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d7102/2)  you can use this link to test

Comment: In some cases it won't work. For example record 1 have 2 `#` values, but our logic is to have records that have all values

Comment: that's what the `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Value) = 2` does for you.. it will only count the # once

Comment: The nice thing about this way is that if the parameters are variable they can be put in a table variable and joined to -- a similar count will give valid results.

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways to do this.

The subquery method:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Id
FROM Table
WHERE Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE Value = '@')
    AND Id IN (SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE Value = '@');
```

The correlated subquery method:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.Id
FROM Table t
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table a WHERE a.Id = t.Id and a.Value = '@')
    AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Table b WHERE b.Id = t.Id and b.Value = '#');
```

And the INTERSECT method:

```
SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE Value = '#'
INTERSECT
SELECT Id FROM Table WHERE Value = '@';
```

Best performance will depend on RDBMS vendor, size of table, and indexes.  Not all RDBMS vendors support all methods.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a multiple self join like this?

```
select
  distinct t1.id
from
  table t1
  join table t2 on (t1.id=t2.id)
  join table t3 on (t1.id=t3.id)
   ...
where
  t1.value='@' and
  t2.value='#' and
  t3.value='$' and
   ...
```

Comment: It is hard to say anything without seeing a plan.
But you can also do something similar with `exists`. And some indexing can usually help too.